# Any Stories of Tzadikim Praying for their Children?

Tags: tefilla, story-identification, tzaddikim, children

I am trying to find some stories of tzadikim praying for the success and righteousness of their children. Are there any?

I remember only one of the Chatam Sofer saying that his hat was full of tears for the success of his son, the Katav Sofer.

Comment: Tefillas Hashl”a. I’m sure he said it himself…..

Comment: The Brisker Rov.

Answer (score 4):

> וַיֹּ֥אמֶר אַבְרָהָ֖ם אֶל־הָֽאֱלֹהִ֑ים ל֥וּ יִשְׁמָעֵ֖אל יִחְיֶ֥ה לְפָנֶֽיךָ׃
>
> And Avraham said to G-d: "May Yishmael live in Your service."
>
> [Bereishis 17:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.18)